# Pushing an array to native storage

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, cordova-nativestorage

I am trying to push an array into native storage on an ionic/cordova android app.

The code I am using is -

```
export class ScanSession {
scans: any [];

constructor(private barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner, private      
nativeStorage: NativeStorage) { 
//this.scans = [];
}

ScanCode() : any{
this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {

let inputString = "testData";

let ts = new Date();

if( barcodeData.text == inputString){
  this.scans.push(ts);
  this.nativeStorage.setItem('scans', (this.scans))
  .then(
    () => console.log('Stored item!'),
    error => console.error('Error storing item', error)
  );
  console.log("Success");
  console.log(this.scans);

} else {
  console.log("Doesnt Match");
}

}, (err) => {

});
};
}
```

It is returning an error saying -

```
Runtime Error
Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[NativeStorage] ...
```

This error is from testing on a browser, however when I test on device it fails to load.

Comment: i think you need to store your array in this way

`this.nativeStorage.setItem('scans', (JSON.stringify(this.scans)))`

Comment: Perfect, it works. Although I've noticed that if I switch between pages in the app, when I then return to the scan page and add a new scan, its writing over what is added to native storage, not adding to it.
I think this is because of the empty array variables I am using, I am adding the array to native storage, but each time I go to the page I am creating an empty array.

What is the best way to get around this?

Comment: i think you don't  need to store the array, You need to store particular scan on the native storage

Comment: I just had that realization a moment ago too. I have changed the code now to -
this.nativeStorage.setItem('scans', ts )
With ts being the current date.
However in testing, each scan overwrites the previous, only 1 scan is ever being stored now

Comment: Ok, Perfect, So do you get your result?

Comment: Not quite. What is happening now is its replacing the previous value in the storage with a new scan date, not adding the new scan to a list/array of old scans.
I need it to be able to store all scans.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163248/discussion-between-mustafa-lokhandwala-and-sunnyj58).